# Differences of TRIM and TRIM BOTH in Spark

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, trim

I have created a Spark SQL temp view named `old_ticket_df`. In the temp view `old_ticket_df` I have a column "approver" which appears to have whitespace. I have tried to remove the whitespace using `trim()`, but it seems to have no effect. If I try instead to remove the whitespace using `trim(BOTH '\t' from approver)` it appears to remove the whitespace.

I have created a Spark dataframe called `compare_df` from the `compare_query` below, where I have unioned two examples together applying the two different versions of the `trim` function to the same field and value. The output from the code is below.

Can someone please tell me what the difference is between `TRIM(approver)` and `TRIM(BOTH '\t' FROM approver)` in Spark SQL?

Code:

```
compare_query="""
select * from (
select 'ver1' as data_source,  TRIM(BOTH '\t' FROM approver) as  approver
from old_ticket_df
where ticketid='xxxxx'
and ticketlineid='yyyyyyy'
and storeid='00'
and dateclosed='2020-06-06'
union
select 'ver2' as data_source, TRIM(approver) as approver
from old_ticket_df
where ticketid='xxxxx'
and ticketlineid='yyyyyyy'
and storeid='00'
and dateclosed='2020-06-06'
)
"""
compare_df=spark.sql(compare_query)
compare_df.show(truncate=False)
```

Output:

```
+-----------+------------------------+
|data_source|approver                |
+-----------+------------------------+
|ver2       |user1@GMAIL.COM         |
|ver1       |user1@GMAIL.COM         |
+-----------+------------------------+
```

Comment: `trim(str) - Removes the leading and trailing space characters from str.` 
`trim(BOTH trimStr FROM str) - Remove the leading and trailing trimStr characters from str` ---- so by default trim removes spaces whereas you can custom input the trim string using both. Docs here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/index.html#trim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`trim(str)` removes only space characters.
`trim(BOTH trimStr FROM str)` removes characters which you specify in `trimStr`.

[Spark's `trim` documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#trim)

Example:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([(' SPACES ', ), ('\tTABS\t', )], ['str'])
df.createOrReplaceTempView("sql_df")
spark.sql("""
SELECT str,
       TRIM(str) as trim,
       TRIM(BOTH '\t' FROM str) as trim_both_tab,
       TRIM(BOTH ' \t' FROM str) as trim_both_tab_space
FROM sql_df
""").show()
#+--------+--------+-------------+-------------------+
#|     str|    trim|trim_both_tab|trim_both_tab_space|
#+--------+--------+-------------+-------------------+
#| SPACES |  SPACES|      SPACES |             SPACES|
#|\tTABS\t|\tTABS\t|         TABS|               TABS|
#+--------+--------+-------------+-------------------+
```

- Column `str` is the original with value " SPACES " (having surrounding space characters) and value "\tTABS\t" (having surrounding tab characters).
- Column `trim` shows the result of `trim(str)`. Space characters were trimmed, but tab characters remain.
- Column `trim_both_tab` shows the result of `TRIM(BOTH '\t' FROM str)`. Tab characters were trimmed, but space characters remain.
- Column `trim_both_tab_space` shows the result of `TRIM(BOTH ' \t' FROM str)`. Both space and tab characters were removed, because they both were provided.

---

In your case, `TRIM(approver)` only removed spaces, so in `ver2` line you still have tabs remaining. While `TRIM(BOTH '\t' FROM approver)` only removed tabs leaving spaces untouched.